# "module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'" when running python-sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to generate a documentation for my python project using Sphinx.
The commands I'm running are:

```
sphinx-quickstart
sphinx-apidoc -o rst .
make html
```

However, when executing the last command, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-p
ackages\sphinx\__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-p
ackages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 51, in main
    sys.exit(build_main(argv))
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-p
ackages\sphinx\__init__.py", line 61, in build_main
    from sphinx import cmdline
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-p
ackages\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 14, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\optpar
se.py", line 421, in <module>
    _builtin_cvt = { "int" : (_parse_int, _("integer")),
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\gettex
t.py", line 514, in gettext
    return dgettext(_current_domain, message)
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\gettex
t.py", line 478, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\gettex
t.py", line 413, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=True)
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\gettex
t.py", line 385, in find
    for nelang in _expand_lang(lang):
  File "C:\winpython-3.5.2.3-win64\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\gettex
t.py", line 114, in _expand_lang
    loc = locale.normalize(loc)
AttributeError: module 'locale' has no attribute 'normalize'
```

I already checked whether there are other locale.py files somewhere, but I couldn't find any. Furthermore, in my own scripts I can import `locale` and call `normalize`.

I'm using python 3.5

Comment: You posted the same question a few minutes ago - in the future, instead of deleting your old question and posting a new one, please [edit] your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I created a Python environment and installed `sphinx` in that environment.

Then from that environment I ran:

```
make html
```

and it worked perfectly.

I think is a problem with the Python versions or, maybe, it gets confused with other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Updating sphinx on my computer solved the issue.

In my case I ran `conda install sphinx`

Comment: What were the old and new versions of Sphinx?

Comment: I don't remember